# Eclipse code completion window suddenly takes up whole screen

Tags: java, eclipse, actionscript-3, flash, ide

I was working in eclipse and the code completion window suddenly started taking up the entire screen width wise. I've tried resetting all my perspectives / quitting reopening the window but it stubbornly staying this way.  Anybody know what setting I should tweak to get it back to normal.

[image: huge code completion]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reset your perspective back to default settings by *Window* » *Reset Perspective...*

[image: reset-perspective]

Otherwise, you can resize the content assist window by grabbing the lower-right corner.

Comment: thanks, no mouse change happened on the bottom corner but i click and dragged anyway and it worked, thanks =]